# reRender outputPanel from javascript function in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I want to reRender  "TopPanel" from javascript, is there any way to do this in visualforce ?

```
<apex:outputPanel id="TopPanel">
<apex:outputPanel>

<script type="text/javascript">
function CreateTabs()
{
    //rerenderCode for TopPanel
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you just simulate clicking on hidden commandlink or something like that that would have `rerender="TopPanel"` in it? I'd think twice before inspecting & emulating the request being sent when commandbutton/link is clicked and response parsed back... I suspect this code could change in future.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is what an actionFunction is for

```
<apex:actionFunction name="rerenderTopPanel" rerender="TopPanel" />
<apex:outputPanel id="TopPanel">
</apex:outputPanel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function createTabs() {
        rerenderTopPanel();
    }
</script>
```